# Data attribute turns into true after event call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, controller, attributes

I have this input:

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="area.id" data-id="{{area.id}}"/>`

and some `ng-click` action above, I'm trying to collect all selected checkboxes id's but after check action `data-id` attribute turns to `true/false`, why?

Function from controller:

```
collectSelectedAreas($event) {
    let selectedArea = $event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    let areaIds = [];

    [selectedArea].forEach((el) => {
        console.log(el.attributes['data-id'].value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are those checkbox inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo yeap, they are in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You could select another property to track the checkbox value (true/false) like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="area.selected" data-id="{{area.id}}"/>
```

area.selected = true in case of checkbox is selected

Then in your function, iterate over your area's Array, lets suppose you have an `arrayOfAreas`, the same array that you are iterating in your `ng-repeat`

```
collectSelectedAreas() {    
    let areaIds = [];

    arrayOfAreas.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.selected){
           areasId.push(el);//Add selected element to array
           console.log(el.id);
        }
    });
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="area.selected" data-id="{{area.id}}" ng-true-value="area.id" ng-false-value="'NO'"/>
```

It means that when checkbox is `checked` area.selected will take the area.id value, otherwise the string 'NO';

Comment: OK, but i need unique ng-model values bc i'm also changing ng-class for this elements

Comment: You can use the area.selected in your ng-class directive as well. I am sure that track the ng-model for a checkbox with the area.id property is not a good idea, if you want to keep the value of the id available.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to access DOM for getting selected checkbox. You can check this by checking the model value `area.id` . It will contain `true` for if checkbox is selected. Then you can traverse through `area` object, where you can get key to identified the id of selected checkbox.For Eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="area.id" />
```

where

```
$scope.area.id==true if checkbox is selected.
```